# R data.table: 2 level grouping with storing result in new columns named by value one of levels

Tags: r, data.table

consider next:

```
dt1 <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), status = c(0,1,1,2,3,0,2), val = c(2,2,4,1,2,3,1))
```

I use group by (id, status) with mean func to make columns with names which consists status values from 0 to 3:

```
stat <- c(0:3)
for(i in 1:length(stat)) dt1[, eval(paste("meanval.stat.", stat[i], sep = "")) := mean(val, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(id, status == stat[i])]
```

with next result:

```
   id status val meanval.stat.0 meanval.stat.1 meanval.stat.2 meanval.stat.3
1:  1      0   2       2.000000           2.00       2.666667       2.666667
2:  1      1   2       3.000000           3.00       2.666667       2.666667
3:  1      1   4       3.000000           3.00       2.666667       2.666667
4:  2      2   1       1.333333           1.75       1.000000       1.666667
5:  2      3   2       1.333333           1.75       2.500000       2.000000
6:  2      0   3       3.000000           1.75       2.500000       1.666667
7:  2      2   1       1.333333           1.75       1.000000       1.666667
```

But I expected another result like next:

```
   id status val meanval.stat.0 meanval.stat.1 meanval.stat.2 meanval.stat.3
1:  1      0   2       2                  3          0              0
2:  1      1   2       2                  3          0              0
3:  1      1   4       2                  3          0              0
4:  2      2   1       3                  0          1              2
5:  2      3   2       3                  0          1              2
6:  2      0   3       3                  0          1              2
7:  2      2   1       3                  0          1              2
```

I dont understand whats wrong with logic of my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the logic would be to group by 'id', subset the 'val' based on logical `vector` created by comparing the 'status' with each of the elements of 'stat', get the `mean`, assign it to new columns ('nm1'), and if there are `NaN`, `set` it to 0

```
nm1 <- paste0("meanval.stat.", stat) 
for(i in seq_along(stat)) {
    dt1[, (nm1) :=  mean(val[status == stat[i]], na.rm = TRUE), .(id)][]
 }

for(j in nm1) {
   set(dt1, i = which(is.nan(dt1[[j]])), j = j, value = 0)[]
}
```

Comment: Not sure why but above solution didn't work for me. I got `NaN` for all rows with `id` as 1.

Comment: @MKR What is your data.table version?  I used `1.10.5`

Comment: Mine is 1.10.4-3.

Comment: @MKR It is working for me based on the example OP provided

Comment: Maybe data.table version is causing a difference. I used data from OP itself.